# Update SQL statement in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

Please I'm creating a page which update username and password

I used this code but it doesn't work

```
String amdef ="model.firstAppModule";
String config="firstAppModuleLocal";
ApplicationModule ami = Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(amdef, config);
firstAppModuleImpl am = (firstAppModuleImpl)ami;

try{
    String sql="UPDATE Employee SET Username='dddd',Password='ffff' WHERE Id=1";
    Statement st = null;

    st = am.getDBTransaction().createStatement(0);

    st.executeUpdate(sql);
}        
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("exception"+e.toString());
}
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the statement creation to look more like this:

st = getDBTransaction().createStatement(sql, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Use your View Objects (based on Entity Ojects) to perform all DML actions.